# Angular Controller Architecture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

So I'm trying to architect a simple Angular controller in a DRY fashion.

Basically a have two views. one is `#/items` the other is `#/archiveditems`

The pages are identical except that one page shows a list of archived items, the other shows current items. Also there is an `<h2>` that looks like `<h2>{{itemState}} Items</h2>`

I have an Angular Factory setup that returns an object that looks like `{items: $resource(/api/items), archivedTtems: $resource(/api/archiveditems)}`

Currently I have two separate controllers. The code is nearly identical in both. The only difference is the `$scope.itemState` and `Api.archivedItems.query()` vs `Api.items.query()`

Here's what the controller looks like in detail.

```
app.controller('currentItemsController', function($scope, Api){

    $scope.itemState = 'Current';

    $scope.items = Api.items.query(function () {

});

app.controller('archivedItemsController', function($scope, Api){

    $scope.itemState = 'Archived';

    $scope.items = Api.archivedItems.query(function () {

});
```

I fell that there is an elegant way I can merge these two controllers into one. Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could have you route setup for /items/:type

and then in controller something like:

```
app.controller('itemsController', function($scope, Api, $routeParams){

    var isArchive = $routeParams.type == 'archived';
    $scope.itemState = isArchive ? 'Archived' : 'Current';
    $scope.items = Api[isArchive ? 'items' : 'archivedItems'].query(function () { ... });

});
```

so then when you call /items/archived - it would deal with your archived items .. also if your API returns the same thing back - why not just pass a flag "isArchived" instead of having a separate resource?

Comment: Yeah I thought about passing a flag or even doing 

`items: $resource('/api/items/:state')` 

But writing `Api.items.query({state: 'archived'})` seemed the same as writing `Api.archivedItems.query()` If there was more than one state then passing a flag seemed to make more sense.